# Unable to save Theme Options when TinyMCE is enabled for the text area

Tags: tinymce, theme-options

On the site I'm currently developing I have created a theme options page (under Appearance). All there is on this page is a text area so the client can add some summary text to appear above their posts.

I am using TinyMCE on this textarea so they can format their text, but if I have TinyMCE enabled the 'Save Options' button doesn't do anything upon clicking it. If I comment out the following lines in my theme-options file to disable TinyMCE, then it saves correctly.

```
<?php
    wp_tiny_mce( false , // true makes the editor "teeny"
        array(
            "editor_selector" => "large-text"
        )
    );
?>
```

*Note:* The TinyMCE loads and displays correctly - text can be formatted, just not saved.

Any idea what could be causing this?

I am using WordPress 3.2.

**Thanks!**

**Edit:** The entire code in my *theme-options.php* file is as follows

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_init', 'theme_options_init' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'theme_options_add_page' );

/**
 * Init plugin options to white list our options
 */
function theme_options_init(){
    register_setting( 'client_options', 'client_theme_options', 'theme_options_validate' );
}

/**
 * Load up the menu page
 */
function theme_options_add_page() {
    add_theme_page( __( 'Intro/Welcome Text', 'client' ), __( 'Intro/Welcome Text', 'client' ), 'edit_theme_options', 'theme_options', 'theme_options_do_page' );
}


/**
 * Create the options page
 */
function theme_options_do_page() {
    global $select_options, $radio_options;

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) )
        $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] = false;

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); echo "<h2>" . __( ' Intro/Welcome Text', 'client' ) . "</h2>"; ?>

        <?php if ( false !== $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) : ?>
        <div class="updated fade"><p><strong><?php _e( 'Options saved', 'client' ); ?></strong></p></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'client_options' ); ?>
            <?php $options = get_option( 'client_theme_options' ); ?>
            <?php
            wp_tiny_mce( true , // true makes the editor "teeny"
                array(
                    "editor_selector" => "large-text"
                )
            );
            ?>
            <table class="form-table">

                <?php
                /**
                 * A sample textarea option
                 */
                ?>
                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Intro/Welcome Text' ); ?></th>
                    <td>
                        <textarea id="client_theme_options[intro_content]" class="large-text" cols="50" rows="10" name="client_theme_options[intro_content]"><?php echo esc_textarea( $options['intro_content'] ); ?></textarea>
                        <label class="description" for="client_theme_options[intro_content]"><?php _e( 'Enter content here to be displayed above the <em><strong>Posts</strong></em>.', 'client' ); ?></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Options', 'client' ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Sanitize and validate input. Accepts an array, return a sanitized array.
 */
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
    global $select_options, $radio_options;

    // Our checkbox value is either 0 or 1
    if ( ! isset( $input['option1'] ) )
        $input['option1'] = null;
    $input['option1'] = ( $input['option1'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );

    // Say our text option must be safe text with no HTML tags
    $input['sometext'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $input['sometext'] );

    // Our select option must actually be in our array of select options
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $input['selectinput'], $select_options ) )
        $input['selectinput'] = null;

    // Our radio option must actually be in our array of radio options
    if ( ! isset( $input['radioinput'] ) )
        $input['radioinput'] = null;
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $input['radioinput'], $radio_options ) )
        $input['radioinput'] = null;

    // Say our textarea option must be safe text with the allowed tags for posts
    $input['sometextarea'] = wp_filter_post_kses( $input['sometextarea'] );

    return $input;
}

// adapted from http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/05/handling-plugins-options-in-wordpress-28-with-register_setting/
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the entire Theme Options page, including the `register_setting()` call and sanitization callback function?

Comment: Thanks for your response - I will update my question accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

What output do you get on-submit, if you add the following to the top of your sanitization callback:

```
var_dump( $input ); die;
```

i.e. add it here:

```
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {
    var_dump( $input ); die;
```

Compare the results **with** and **without TinyMCE**. Let's figure out what's changing.

Also: this isn't *directly* related to the issue you're having (at least, I *think* it isn't), but your sanitization callback doesn't actually sanitize the input you're sending it, i.e. `client_theme_options['intro_text']`. It appears to be a conglomeration of copy-pasta, example sanitization functions.

You need to sanitize your *actual* option, probably with a `wp_filter_post_kses()` filter, since you're allowing for HTML input.

**EDIT**

Perhaps you are having a similar issue to [this other SO questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122085/problem-jquery-and-tinymce-textarea-value-doesnt-submit), in which the textarea data isn't being submitted, because of the way that TinyMCE hijacks the textarea?

The solutions to that question included:

- before submit call tinyMCE.triggerSave();
- And this suggestion:

Add a hidden field to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="question_html" name="question_html" />
```

Before posting the form, get the data from the editor and put in the hidden field:

```
$('#question_html').val(tinyMCE.get('question_text').getContent());
```

Here's [another SO question related to the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658029/wordpress-tinymce-not-submitting-content). It suggests using this script code:

```
var editor = tinymce.get( editor_id);
editor.save();  // writes content back to the textarea
// you may now use jQuery or editor.getContent(); to acces the content
```

(Which I think is similar to the other suggestions.)

Not sure if any of those would be helpful?

Comment: It appears the form is never getting submitted at all. IE the page never reloads. Also no error message is displayed. Note: there are also no JS errors on the page.

Comment: So, when you click "submit", *nothing* at all happens? Is that true both with and without TinyMCE enabled?

Comment: With TinyMCE disabled, the form submits fine and the page reloads with the new value in the textarea. Only with TinyMCE enabled does the submit button not work.

Comment: So, you didn't add `var_dump( $input ); die;` to your sanitization callback function? You need to do that, so we can diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Hi, with TinyMCE disabled, I get the following from the var_dump():

array(1) { ["intro_content"]=> string(56) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." }

Comment: And what about with TinyMCE enabled? Do you get the same `var_dump()`, something different, or nothing at all?

Comment: With TinyMCE enabled the form never submits - ie. clicking the button, it's as if nothing has happened.

Comment: What is the code/markup for your submit button?

Comment: The markup for the submit button is as follows: <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Options', 'client' ); ?>" />

Comment: Okay, added some other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for hte suggestions Chip, I will give them a try!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after a day of frustration I found that if I added the `wp_tiny_mce` inside the table it worked.

```
    <table class="form-table">

    <tr>
    <td>
                <?php
wp_tiny_mce( false , // true makes the editor "teeny"
  array(
    "editor_selector" => "mce-text",
  'width' => '80%',
  'theme' => 'advanced',
  'skin' => 'wp_theme'
  )
);
    ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
```